# Latitude & Longitude values from Simple Voyage Data Recorder [SVDR]

Tags: coordinate-system, gps, nmea

I am receiving values in the form of `0113.7276,N,10339.0121,E` from a Ship Data Recorder. I am not a GIS/ GPS expert and am unable to decipher what do these values mean, because they are out of range for standard latitude and longitude values.

What could these values mean?

Comment: You need to convert them from DMm 1.228793,103.650201 jurong island singapore. converter  http://www.hiddenvision.co.uk/ez/?nmea_lat=0113.7276%2CN&nmea_lon=10339.0121%2CE

Comment: Thank you @Mapperz! Do you think the explanation given by martinr in the post: http://www.mapwindow.org/phorum/read.php?3,16271,16310 is correct, according to which this should be 1 deg 13.7276 min North and 103 deg 39.0121 min East?

Comment: Would you be able to edit your question to indicate what SVDR is short for, please?

Comment: Yes, the format is clearly the same that is used in NMEA messages, for example in GGA. Example from http://www.trimble.com/OEM_ReceiverHelp/V4.44/en/NMEA-0183messages_GGA.html `$GPGGA,172814.0,3723.46587704,N,12202.26957864,W,2,6,1.2,18.893,M,-25.669,M,2.0,0031*4F`

Comment: Related questions (not really dupe since there's a specific device identified here): http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/94711/help-identifying-a-coordinate-system/94733#94733 and http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/9295/why-are-the-formats-of-these-coordinates-different/9296#9296

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The values you gave are for 1°13.7276'N, 103°39.0121'E, which as @Mapperz said in his comment, corresponds to 1.228793°N, 103.650201°E.  The format is 2 digits for latitude (00-90 inclusive) or 3 digits for longitude (000-180 inclusive) in degrees of arc, followed by 2 digits (00-59 inclusive) for minutes of arc, followed by the decimal portion of the minutes of arc, in this case to 4 digits (roughly 1m precision), or more formally, `[D]DDMM.mmmm,H` with the `H` standing for the hemisphere.